# Logging in Windows 7 takes only seconds while logging in Windows 10 takes several minutes

Tags: windows, log4net

I've run into an issue when using log4net.  The following application was run on Windows 7 and Windows 10.  There is a significant performance difference.  This was tried on multiple Windows 10 machines with a similar result.

**Log4net version:**  2.0.8.0

**Windows 7:**  6 seconds
**Windows 10:**  2 minutes and 17 seconds 
**Windows 10 Info:**  Version 1809.  OS Build:  17763.253 (This build has already been patched:  [KB4058258 (OS Build 16299.214)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4057154/performance-of-system-diagnostics-stackframe-degrades-in-windows-10)).
**.NET version:**  4.6.1

**test.log4net.config**

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="c:\temp\myLog.log" />
    <appendToFile value="false" />
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%5level [%thread] (%file:%line) - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="All" />
    <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

**Program.cs**

```
using log4net;
using log4net.Config;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleAppPerfTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo("test.log4net.config"));
            var t = new Test();
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            t.RunTest();
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Minutes: {0}", sw.Elapsed.TotalMinutes);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        private readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Test));

        public void RunTest()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 22000; i++)
            {
                _log.DebugFormat("test logging something: {0}", i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, when you remove this line from `test.log4net.config` the performance in Windows 10 runs as fast if not faster than Windows 7:

```
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
```

[image]

Comment: Wondering if some other program might be accessing the file... can you temporarily switch of the real-time protection of whatever antivirus program is running on the W10 machines?

Comment: @AndrewMorton - Wow.  Disabling windows defender real time protection fixed it.  Great find!  I'm baffled why this issue only exists when the config is set with the `lockingModel`?

Comment: I *guess* that the default locking is strong/weak enough that Windows Defender doesn't get a look-in or doesn't have to struggle to access the file.